# What does [ ] mean in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like below and some JQuery syntax to place data on the array into a table.  Everything is working fine, but

1. I don't quite understand the keys [ ] mean! such as `"<td>" + dateList[i]["name"] + "</td>";`
2. If the data isn't an array, but it is a XML, or JSON, is `"<td>" + dateList[i]["name"] + "</td>";` still working?

   var dateList =[
     {
           name: "Mike Jenson",
           email: "mike_j@yesware.com",
           phone: "9433550193",
           joined: "05/23/2014",
       },
       {
           name: "Jim Stevens",
           email: "jim_s@yesware.com",
           phone: "1299331944",
           joined: "05/22/2014"
       }

   ```
   ];

       $("#myTable").html("");
       for (var i=0; i< dateList.length; i++)
       {
           var tr="<tr>";
           var td1 = "<td>" + dateList[i]["name"] + "</td>";
           var td2 = "<td>" + dateList[i]["email"] + "</td>";
           var td3 = "<td>" + dateList[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
           var td4 = "<td>" + dateList[i]["joined"] + "</td></tr>";
           $('#myTable').append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);
       }
   ```

Comment: Those are called property accessors. You can read all about them here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Stackoverflow really isn't the best way to learn the basic syntax of the language. You'd be better off finding a tutorial web site or buying a book.

Comment: for e.g dateList[0]["name"] means "access the name property of the object located in position 0 of the array"

Comment: What you have is an array (declared with `[]`) of objects (each declared with `{}`). Using `dateList[i]["name"]` will not work with XML or JSON (both of which are string formats that would need to be parsed first to create an object or array).

Comment: Thank you, to bmceldowney, Paul Tomblin and nnnnnn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` is used in arrays to specify the index we need to access, when we say:

`someArray[0]` we are getting the value from array's first index and in your case it is

specifying the index via variable which is coming from the loop and in second it is

specifying object's property to get the property value from that index which is passed in 1st `[]`:

```
dateList[i]["name"]
```

in this case it will return you the `ith` index element of array's name property value.

if  you say `dateList[0]["name"]` it will reutrn **"Mike Jenson"** because it is the value

of first array object's name property value.

An alterantive is `dateList[0].name` this will also return the same result.

Comment: But `"name"` isn't an an index!

Comment: agreed @Paul S. name is property of object and corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains objects like this ...

```
datalist[0] = {"name":"somename", "email":"someemail", /* contains at least 4 properties */}
datalist[1] = {"name":"somename", "email":"someemail", /* contains at least 4 properties */}
```

datalist[0].email and datalist[0]["email"] both access the same object property of the first element of the array.